# Pandas multiindex from list of nested records

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have some data in a structure like this:

```
data = [
        {"name": "Jack", "last_name": "Black", "sizes": {"shoes": 43, "waist": 48, "chest":52}},
        {"name": "Mario", "last_name": "Green", "sizes": {"shoes": 42, "waist": 53, "chest":63}}
]
```

how can i get a dataframe that looks like this easily?:

```
name  last_name sizes
name  last_name shoes waist chest
Jack  Black      43     48    52
Mario Green      42     53    63
```

i know that i can use

```
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

but it's not exactly the same

and how could i do it if the data was a dict of records like this:

```
data = {
        12345: {"name": "Jack", "last_name": "Black", "sizes": {"shoes": 43, "waist": 48, "chest":52}},
        78910: {"name": "Mario", "last_name": "Green", "sizes": {"shoes": 42, "waist": 53, "chest":63}}
}
```

and i wanted to get:

```
      name  last_name sizes
      name  last_name shoes waist chest
12345 Jack  Black      43     48    52
78910 Mario Green      42     53    63
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a dataframe with json normalize then set the index to first and last name now split the remaining columns to convert to multiindex

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
df = df.set_index(['name', 'last_name'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
```

---

```
                sizes            
                shoes waist chest
name  last_name                  
Jack  Black        43    48    52
Mario Green        42    53    63
```